# How to capture stdout from a console application whose life cycle is very long by CreatePipe?

Tags: console, hide, readfile, createprocess, blocked

I tried to write an test application to capture the text from stdout of an 3rd console application.

I studied from many articles to use the CreatePipe API and have INDEED obtained the text AFTER the console application HAD FINISHED running.

I tried to make the console application keep printing something for more than 60 seconds, and the ReadFile funcion didn't return during this 60 seconds at all.

For the same purpose, I tried popen and fread, and everything went fine except the black console window created by popen.

Although the ReadFileEx and something about the overlapped I/O seems to be able to solve this problem but it's actually not.

Because the ReadFileEx required the file handle to be created to support overlapping, and this is always impossilbe because the file handle is created by the 3rd console application. It won't be under control unless we develop the console application by ourselves.

So is there any way to capture stdout from a 3rd console application whose life cycle is very long by CreatePipe?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I finaly figured out the problem is the 3rd console application "MAC.EXE" doesn't invoke "fflush" after each progress output....

I manually append the fflush operation in the source code of mac.exe and the problem gets resolved.

So a new question is:
If the child process never call fflush and seldom print during running, how to read the content correctly?

Comment: I tried to force the stdout to flush and use FlushFileBuffers in the client application, but it fails and GetLastError() returns 6 (Invalid handle).

I am so sad, the handled created by me can be written by the 3rd application and reject flushing from myself....